# Instance value in view is diplayed after page refresh(Production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, instance-variables

I'm using rails 2.3.4 & ruby 1.8.7

I'm trying to print a instance variable in my application.

The instance variable is getting initialized in a method in `deal_portal/base_controller.rb`, while the view is rendered from a method in `deal_portal/mobile_controller`. When I view the page, the value of instance variable is not present, but once the page is refreshed the value is displayed.

What could be the cause of delay as this happens only in production

EDIT:

deal_portal/base_controller.rb

```
def validate_trans
  @voucher_urls = payment_info["voucher_urls"]
end
```

deal_portal/mobile_controller.rb

```
class DealPortal::MobileController < DealPortal::BaseController
  def payment_success
    render :template => "deal_portal/mobile/payment_success.html.erb"
  end
end
```

deal_portal/mobile_native_app_controller.rb

```
class DealPortal::MobileNativeAppController < DealPortal::BaseController     
  before_filter :validate_trans, :only => [:payment_success]
end
```

Now in the view file `payment_success.html.erb` after the puchase is made, the `@voucher_urls` is not displayed and after refreshing the page, it becomes visible.

Comment: Hi GhostRider, could u provide some code here..

Comment: @sameera207, just check the edit

Comment: I am trying to exercise my psychic powers, but ... please explain how the `validate_trans` is called in the `mobile_controller`? I am assuming the `mobile_controller` derives from the `base_controller`.

Comment: @nathanvda...correct. this is how it's done                      class DealPortal::MobileController < DealPortal::BaseController

Comment: @GhostRider you're still not telling how you call `validate_trans`, could you post this code as well?

Comment: @GhostRider, one simple test you could do is, just add a 'puts' in validate_tran and see how many times it has been called, any way as Garret said, if you could provide more code that would be helpful. As you mentioned, seems like there is an inheritance also

Comment: okk..i'll update the code and also check by using puts..

Comment: class DealPortal::MobileNativeAppController < DealPortal::BaseController
before_filter :validate_trans, :only => [:payment_success] @benoit

Comment: @sameera207.. validate_trans is called only once

Comment: 1. Please check methods callback chain with 'puts' or rails logger. Be sure 'validate_trans' evaluates before 'payment_success'.
2. Not sure it can cause such an errors, but try to pass Symbol-param instead of Array for ':only' option.